# DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'userid'

Tags: asp.net, count, eval, repeater

I want to find the total number of active users who are members of the `user` table in my database. But I get an error like this:

> DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with name 'userid'

My code is as follows:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <h3><%#Eval("userid") %></h3>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:aytasarimConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [user]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that there is no column named `userid` in the result from your query. And that makes sense since you are returning only one column. And you are not even naming that column with `AS`, so SQL makes it `Expr1` as column name.

your query should be

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_users FROM [user]
```

Now you can use the column name `total_users` in the Repeater

```
<h3><%#Eval("total_users") %></h3>
```